# Xdebug and VIm: unfolding the entire array children in the debuggerwatch window

Tags: vim, xdebug

I am using vdebug and vim to debug php scripts.

After starting the debugger i can see the array values with first childs in a uncollapsed manner in the debuggerwatch widow.

```
▾ $wp_filter = (array [365])
  \
   ▸ $wp_filter['pre_term_name'] = (array [2])
   |
   ▸ $wp_filter['pre_comment_author_name'] = (array [2])
   |
   ▸ $wp_filter['pre_link_name'] = (array [2])
   |
   ▸ $wp_filter['pre_link_target'] = (array [2])
   |
   ▸ $wp_filter['pre_link_rel'] = (array [2])
```

I have a vary big (365 elements) array with 3 childrens inside each first child of array

In the vims debugger watch window, it shows an arrow in the array only till the first child. If you click it collapses futher to show the children.

```
▾ $wp_filter = (array [365])
  \
   ▾ $wp_filter['pre_term_name'] = (array [2])
    \
     ▾ $wp_filter['pre_term_name'][10] = (array [2])
      \
       ▾ $wp_filter['pre_term_name'][10]['sanitize_text_field'] = (array [2])
        \
         ⬦ $wp_filter['pre_term_name'][10]['sanitize_text_field']['function'] = (string [19]) `sanitize_text_field`
         |
         ⬦ $wp_filter['pre_term_name'][10]['sanitize_text_field']['accepted_args'] = (int) 1
        /
       ▸ $wp_filter['pre_term_name'][10]['wp_filter_kses'] = (array [2])
      /
     ▸ $wp_filter['pre_term_name'][30] = (array [1])
    /
   ▸ $wp_filter['pre_comment_author_name'] = (array [2])
   |
   ▸ $wp_filter['pre_link_name'] = (array [2])
   |
   ▸ $wp_filter['pre_link_target'] = (array [2])
   |
   ▸ $wp_filter['pre_link_rel'] = (array [2])
```

SO is there a way i can collapse till the last level of the array for all the array elements at once, instead of presseing the arrow manually. I tried the unfolding command `zo`. It says no folds found.

Comment: FYI.  Your question pertains to vdebug more than vim or xdebug.  I recommend searching the list of issues on github.com/joonty/vdebug for a similar question.  if not found, then open an issue and request folding support in the watch window as a feature.  You might also try #vdebug on freenode IRC.

Answer (score 1):

I assume meant expand instead of collapse, since expanding a complex variable will show its contents.

While trying to fix an issue with seeing more than 32 elements in arrays with Xdebug + Vdebug.  I may have stumbled across a solution for you.

When I set max_depth to 32 in Vdebug, I found that my watch list auto-expanded nested structures like your asking about.

In Vim, run the ex command...

```
let g:vdebug_features['max_depth']=32
```

And see if that achieves the effect your after.

Comment: INstead we have to use 2048. this variable is not related to expanding, but to show the number of elements in a array.

Comment: Not according to the [Xdebug docs](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#var_display_max_children) it's not.    Adjusting `max_children` on my system increased the number of elements shown in an array.  Adjusting `max_depth` increased arrays within arrays within arrays I could see (and had the noticable effect of auto-expanding them in my Vdebug watch window).  I'll admit the noticable effect may not occur for everyone.